# How to substract two cells of x row on excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm making an Excel sheet to keep track of some activities. The thing is that I have 2 cells that are date type; I want the third cell to subtract the them to get the time that the x person spent on the activity.

I know that if I type `=A2-A1` it's going to give me what I want, but, since its going to be a big Excel sheet with lots of records, I don't want to input the same formula for each row just changing the row  number.

Is there a way to make Excel detect the row that the user is inputing data in and then make the requested formula to get the time?

Comment: Have a look to Excel Scripting

Comment: This is a "How do I use Excel* question which is not related to programming, and therefore it belongs on [su] instead. I've helped you out by fixing the typos, spelling, punctuation, and formatting issues, so you should be able to copy and paste it into a new question there (before deleting it here). For info on the types of questions that are appropriate for any site, review the guidelines in the site's [help]. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can turn your data range into a table by highlighting the range and going to the insert tab and clicking table. Then when you type the formula into the first cell and click in the cells when selecting instead of typing it out, you will notice that it is using the column names instead,  also it will automatically fill the column with the new formula.  That would be my suggestion.